# To find the name of an image file that does not contain a specific rgb list for an image in a folder

Tags: python, image, for-loop

I need to save the name of the image that does not contain the following rgb values, but if I simply use for, it seems to take too long to process, so I am looking for a way to solve it

How do I solve this?

```
list =[[137,68,68],
[168,112,0],
[158,38,0],
[20,86,195],
[19,92,192],]
```

Comment: there are multiple ways to do it, 1. first use multiprocessing to process those images in batches parallelly 2. Use numpy to the matrix processing not python list

Comment: Are there lots of images in the folder? Do you mean you want the name of any one image that doesn't contain any of the colours, or the names of all the images that don't contain all the colours, or something else?